# Unable to connect zookeeper node externally

Tags: apache-zookeeper, mesos, dcos

I have a DCOS cluster spun up using the cloudformation template here:

https://downloads.dcos.io/dcos/stable/aws.html

I'm able to connect remotely to the default dcos zookeeper after the default installation

```
telnet <public_zk_default_node_ip> 2181
```

however when I install the kafka-zookeeper service, I'm unable to connect to those zookeeper nodes over telnet from a remote host.

```
telnet <public_kafka_zk_node> 1140
```

1140 is the default port set by kafka-zookeeper.  The node I'm trying to connect to has a public IP with the appropriate security group settings.  I've opened up all tcp/udp traffic to the remote host and I still can't connect

Any thoughts as to what configuration settings I should be looking at in order to access the kafka-zookeeper nodes externally?

Comment: Sorry didn't totally understand the connection with Drill here. Can you please share some more information ?

Comment: @Sorabh the question itself was unrelated to Drill, though I came to this example through my attempts to access drill nodes externally using zookeeper.  I'll remove the drill tag